# Weird regex bug in iis url-rewrite

Tags: asp.net, regex, url-rewriting, web-config

This is my pattern:

```
^(\w{2}-\w{2})/questions(?:/(\w+))?(?:/(\d+))?(?:/.*?)?$
```

these are the what I'm testing:

```
en-us/questions/ask
en-us/questions/newest/15
en-us/questions/12/just-a-text-to-be-ignored
```

It works perfectly, here is the demo:

https://regex101.com/r/yC3tI8/1

but the following rewrite rule:

```
<rule name="en-us questions" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(\w{2}-\w{2})/questions(?:/(\w+))?(?:/(\d+))?(?:/.*?)?$" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/questions.aspx?lang={R:1}&amp;tab={R:2}&amp;pid={R:3}" />
</rule>
```

when I give the link `en-us/questions/newest` redirects to: `/questions.aspx?lang=en-us&tab=&pid=`

What is wrong with this? Its now about 5 hours I'm just reviewing the same things

Comment: Wouldn't `ask` do the same thing, and what is your expected result?

Comment: yes it would do the same thing but `/newest` was example give it a try with ask, I'm expecting : `/questions.aspx?lang=en-us&tab=newest&pid=15`

Comment: or `/questions.aspx?lang=en-us&tab=ask&pid=` or `/questions.aspx?lang=en-us&tab=&pid=15`

Comment: The problem is that neither `en-us/questions/newest` or `en-us/questions/ask` have a third capture group like `en-us/questions/newest/15`, so `pid` will always be blank.

Comment: well pid might be blank but not always. will it be blank in here: `en-us/questions/newest/15` or here: `en-us/questions/12/just-a-text-to-be-ignored` and my first problem is that as it rewrites to questions.aspx so it matches the pattern. lets say pid will be blank but why the tab is always blank?

Comment: Try using [the regex debugger with substitutions](https://regex101.com/r/gP4wL6/2) so you can see what the result should be.

Comment: but in all of the tab is not empty. do you have a suggestion for the pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have three different possible url endings that ultimately effect the outcome of the rewritten url you can either setup one all inclusive rule that will *hopefully* match everything you want, or you could setup three rules to handle each accordingly:

**One Rule:**

```
^(\w{2}-\w{2})/questions/(\w+)/?(\d+)?.*$
```

> https://regex101.com/r/dN8bM9/1  - tries to handle all cases

```
<rule name="en-us questions" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(\w{2}-\w{2})/questions/(\w+)/?(\d+)?.*$" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/questions.aspx?lang={R:1}&amp;tab={R:2}&amp;pid={R:3}" />
</rule>
```

<sub>* note: one possible reason the original pattern was failing to capture the second group was the inclusion of `(?:)` - which means match but don't capture; leaving that out might solve most of the issues there.</sub>

**Three Rules:**

```
^(\w{2}-\w{2})/questions/(\w+)$
```

> https://regex101.com/r/lI8bQ1/1  - en-us/questions/[single word]

```
^(\w{2}-\w{2})/questions/(\d+)/.*$
```

> https://regex101.com/r/hV5fK3/1  - en-us/questions/[digits]/discard

```
^(\w{2}-\w{2})/questions/(\w+)/(\d+)$
```

> https://regex101.com/r/kO0dJ0/1  - en-us/questions/[single
>   word]/[digits]

Putting it all together into a ruleset:

```
<rule name="en-us questions case one" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(\w{2}-\w{2})/questions/(\w+)$" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/questions.aspx?lang={R:1}&amp;tab={R:2}" />
</rule>  
<rule name="en-us questions case two" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(\w{2}-\w{2})/questions/(\d+)/.*$" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/questions.aspx?lang={R:1}&amp;tab={R:2}" />
</rule>  
<rule name="en-us questions case three" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(\w{2}-\w{2})/questions/(\w+)/(\d+)$" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/questions.aspx?lang={R:1}&amp;tab={R:2}&amp;pid={R:3}" />
</rule>
```

<sub>* note: you might need to adjust this in some way, but it should give you an idea of how to accomodate three different variations (as you seem to have) for rewriting your urls.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, I devided into 2 rules and now working great. I actually was chalenging myself to do it in one rule. I know that it can be done but I couldn't. Thanks again for your nice answer

Answer (score 0):

Note you have three lazy captures:

1. `(?:/(\w+))?`
2. `(?:/(\d+))?`
3. `(?:/.*?)?`

[asp.net's regex implementation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972966.aspx#regexnet_topic5) interprets `?` as:

> In addition to specifying that a given pattern may occur exactly 0 or 1 time, the `?` character also forces a pattern or subpattern to match the minimal number of characters when it might match several in an input string.

So asp.net is assigning no characters to **1**, no characters to **2**, and collecting the rest of the characters **3**.

To use greedy matching instead of the lazy matching `?` forces use: `{0,1}`

So you're regex should look like:

```
^(\w{2}-\w{2})/questions(?:/(\w+)){0,1}(?:/(\d+)){0,1}(?:/.*?)?$
```

[Live example](https://regex101.com/r/uB0mN4/2)

Comment: I'm really very sorry my internet connection have a problem and disconnects. I tried this and still the result is exactly the same

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani Hmm... I'm surprised by that. I think that you need to first confirm how your regex implementation is actually matching and then work on fixing it. For example, is my assumption correct that it's putting the rest of the link in capture **3**? You could determine that by doing: `^(\w{2}-\w{2})/questions(?:/(\w+))?(?:/(\d+))?(/.*?)?$` and printing capture **4**.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani If that is in fact how your regex implementation works, maybe you could try implementing a regex that just matches the start instead of all the string: `^(\w{2}-\w{2})/questions(?:/(\w+))(?:/(\d*))`